# How can I update all fields in a table row by selecting a value from a dropdown menu in my first column?

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js, onchange

I am quite new to NODEJS, EXPRESS and HANDLEBARS.

When inserting a new record into ITEMSUSED, I first query a table "STOCK" to list items from STOCK in a dropdown menu.

When a listed stock item is selected I want all the other fields in that ITEMUSED row to be updated with the relevant information from the dropdown STOCK "table".

i.e.

TABLE = ITEMSUSED

Fields itemnr, description, salesprice

TABLE = STOCK
Fields itemnr, description, salesprice

When an itemnr is selected from the STOCK dropdown menu the fields in the ITEMSUSED (table) must be updated accordingly.

Below is my code

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="top-label">Spares Used for Job {{ thisjobnr }}</h1>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
<div class="top-menu">      
    <a href="/jobs/updatejob/{{ thisjobnr }}" class="btnGeneral">Back</a>  
</div>      
</div>
<p></p>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;" >   
<table class="table center">
<thead>
  <tr> 
    <th class="tblabel th">Part Number</th> 
    <th class="tblabel th">Description</th>
    <th class="tblabel th">Quantity</th>
    <th class="tblabel th text-right">Sales Price</th>
    <th class="tblabel th text-right">Action</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{#each rows}}
  <tr>
    <td class="tbtext td" type="text" name="partnr" value="{{partnr}}">{{partnr}}</td>
    <td class="tbtext td" type="text" name="descriptionz" value="{{description}}">    {{description}}</td>
    <td class="tbtext td" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{quantity}}">{{quantity}}</td>
    <td class="tbtext td" type="text" name="sales_price" value="{{sales_price}}">{{sales_price}}    </td>

    <td>
      <form action="/parts/delete/{{partnr}}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_nr" value="{{job_nr}}">
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="select">
        <select name="partnr" id="partnr" onchange="updateFields(this.id)"   onfocus="" required> 
                {{#selected stockItems.partnr}} 
                    {{#each stockItems}} 
                        <option value="{{partnr}}" required>  {{partnr}}</option>
                    {{else}}
                        <option required>Select make </option>
                    {{/each}}       
                {{/selected}}   
        </select> 
        </div>          
    <td><input type="text" name="description"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sales_price"></td>
    <td>
      <form action="/parts/addit/{{partnr}}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="job_nr" value="{{job_nr}}">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
function updateFields(select) {
  const row = select.parentNode.parentNode;
  const selectedPartNr = select.value;
  const options = select.options;
  const selectedOption = options[select.selectedIndex];

  // Update other fields in the same row HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!
  row.querySelector('[name="description"]').value = selectedOption.text;
  row.querySelector('[name="sales_price"]').value = selectedOption.text;
}
</script>

<script>
function _(element)
{return document.getElementById(element);}
function fetch_data(parent_element, child_element, type)
{   
 fetch('/parts/get_stock?type='+type+'&parent_value='+parent_element.value+'')
 .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
.then(function(responseData)        
    {
        var html = '';
        if(type == 'fetch_stock')
        {
            html = '<option value="">Select a part</option>';
        }
        for(var count = 0; count < responseData.length; count++)
        {
            html += '<option value="'+responseData[count].Data+'">'+responseData[count].Data+'</option>';
        }
        child_element.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
_('partnr').onfocus = function(){
    fetch_data(_('partnr'), _('partnr'), 'fetch_stock');
};
</script>
```

Comment: To me, you have not made it clear what your issue is. Would you be able to rephrase it such that what you expect versus what is actually happening is explicit?

Comment: When I click on the dropdown menu in Column 1 the other fields/column values, in the table on the same row are supposed to be populated with the corresponding field values from the dropdown table, However this is not happening with the code provided Hope this a bit clearer

Comment: `onfocus` seems like the wrong event to which to bind. I think `onchange` would be more appropriate as you want to take an action when the value of the select menu changes. Do you find that the fetch call is being made? If so, do you get a successful response from the `/parts/get_stock` endpoint?